# Get display resolution from the command line for Linux Desktop

Tags: linux, xorg, display-settings

I'm looking for a method of reporting display resolution. I want to set up scripts to launch `rdesktop`, and I want to launch it on several machines with different resolutions, so I want a way to dynamically determine it.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2672/getting-and-setting-screen-size-for-xorg

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use the command `xrandr`. Without any argument it displays the available resolutions and the current one (with an asterisk), for instance:

```
$ xrandr | fgrep '*'
```

Comment: Could you append some sample output to the answer? And I'm guessing `xrandr |g grep \*` does the trick?

Answer (score 13):

Alternative solution: `xdpyinfo | grep dimensions`. `xdpyinfo` is older than `xrandr`, so might be more portable if you happen to use a very old distribution or some different X server.

Comment: Indeed, but some (all ?) multi-monitor setups appear as one screen in `xdpyinfo` while `xrandr` correctly enumerates screens and their resolution. This may or may not be a problem depending on the context.

Comment: Note: while `xdpyinfo` seems to report correct dimensions in pixels, it reports wrong resolution (DPI). E.g. on my monitor with dimesions 3840x2160 (native and actual) and size 708mm x 399mm as reported by `xrandr`, `xdpyinfo` says that resolution is 96x96 dots per inch.

Answer (score 10):

You can get the horizontal and vertical resolutions using the following command:

```
xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | awk '{print $2}' | awk -Fx '{print $1, $2}'
```

or, in more compact form (as suggested by Peter.O in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/418699/get-display-resolution-from-the-command-line-for-linux-desktop/612942#comment1208099_612942) comment):

```
xdpyinfo | awk -F'[ x]+' '/dimensions:/{print $3, $4}'
```

For exmaple, on a 1600x900 display this will produce the following output:

```
1600 900
```

You can then place the values into separate variables using the command:

```
read RES_X RES_Y <<<$(xdpyinfo | awk -F'[ x]+' '/dimensions:/{print $3, $4}')
```

Display the values of the above variables using the command:

```
echo $RES_X, $RES_Y
```

On a 1600x900 display, the output is:

```
1600, 900
```

Comment: xdpyinfo  | awk -F'[ x]+' '/dimensions:/{print $3, $4}'

Comment: @Peter.O, thanks. This is a nice compact form of the command. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Indeed, but some (all ?) multi-monitor setups appear as one screen in xdpyinfo while xrandr correctly enumerates screens and their resolution. This may or may not be a problem depending on the context.

Answer (score 5):

I should have looked a little harder before posting. `xrandr` will echo the current display settings, if not given any other arguments.

By default, this will dump all possible display settings, this can be filtered as follows:

```
xrandr | egrep '^[^ ]|[0-9]\*\+'
```

Answer (score 2):

## Clean `xrandr` output for imagemagick use

```
xrandr |awk '/\*/ {print $1}'
```

The `/\*/` searches for the line containing an asterisk `*`.

Comment: To search with awk directly, instead of grep: `xrandr | awk '/\*/ {print $1}'`