# How to find supported screen resolution on linux, fedora and centOS

Tags: linux, resolution

I'm trying to figure out how to find the screen resolutions available for a linux machine. If you set the wrong resolution or set vga=ask then it prompts you for available resolutions. Is there a way I can find that list somewhere after boot?

Comment: I've not tried it in ages, but I believe when you do `vga=ask`, it will be possible to list the options. So you do that once and then you change it to whatever you've set that first time.

Comment: I need to do this across hundreds of machines and need to be able to easily find the options without setting the grub, rebooting, finding the number, setting it and reboot again. If I could find a list, wherever the ask option gets it from I can find it, set it reboot and not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

## X

If `X` is running, you can use

```
$ xdpyinfo  | grep 'dimensions:'
```

or

```
$ xrandr | fgrep '*'
```

or run your desktop monitor configuration tool.

See also [Get display resolution from the command line for Linux Desktop](https://superuser.com/q/418699/98857).

## Console

As root from the console:

```
# hwinfo --framebuffer
```

[`hwinfo`](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Hwinfo) is a SuSE tool, also available for

- [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/admin/hwinfo)
- [RedHat](http://techtips.biz/how-to-install-hwinfo-on-fedora-1920-and-centos-56/)

See also [How to set the resolution in text consoles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17027/31443).

Comment: I forgot to mention that it's console mode. X is turned off.

Comment: @user3692312: see edit

Comment: hwinfo is not a valid command on any of the machines I've tried. Is there an equivalent for Fedora or CentOS?

Comment: @user3692312: see edit

Comment: So, i still don't have the option of using the hwinfo command on any of these machines from RH Enterprise to Fedora to CentOS. It seems installing it would be just as much work as finding and setting up each machine. Any other suggestions?

Comment: if you have a few identical boxes, you can build `hwinfo` on one and `scp` to all the others.